# Is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{n^2+(-1)^n}$ absolute convergent,conditional convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{n^2+(-1)^n}$ absolute convergent,conditional convergent or divergent ?

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} |\frac{(-1)^n }{n^2+(-1)^n}| =\frac{1}{|n^2+(-1)^n|}$

now $|n^2+(-1)^n| > n^2 - 2 $

=>$\frac{1}{|n^2+(-1)^n|}<1/(n^2 - 2)$

$1/(n^2 - 2)$ is convergent by Limit comparison test with $1/n^2$

therefore,$\frac{1}{|n^2+(-1)^n|}$ is convergent by comparison test
Therefore, case of absolute convergence?
is this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\left |\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+(-1)^n}\right |= \frac{1}{n^2+(-1)^n} \le \frac{1}{n^2-1}$$

for all $n.$ Now $\sum 1/(n^2-1)$ should remind you of $\sum 1/n^2,$ which converges. Indeed, by the limit comparsion test, we see that $\sum 1/(n^2-1)$ converges. This shows the series in this problem converges absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{n^2+(-1)^n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^2+1}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2-1}$

with

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n)^2+1}\leq \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}$

and

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2-1}=\frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})=\frac{1}{4}$

Therefore

$|\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n }{n^2+(-1)^n}|\leq \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2+(-1)^n}\leq \frac{\pi^2}{24}+\frac{1}{4}$

=> absolute convergence

Comment: In the last line, you put absolute values inside the sum. Second, Weierstrass M and uniform convergence have nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: @ zhw. : It has to do with it, but is more general (I've removed it because it's not necessary, that's right). And of course there are absolute values inside the series (not: sum) because I used $|\sum\limits_{n=2}a_n|\leq \sum\limits_{n=2}|a_n|$ for the absolute convergence.

Comment: The problem is that $\sum a_n$ has no meaning as a number at that point in your proof. You haven't shown the series converges yet, so what do you mean by its absolute value? It's a point of logic.

Comment: @zhw. : "$\sum_n a_n$ convergies abolutely" if $\sum_n |a_n|<\infty$ , that's all ...